# Parsing a structured Text / Lua Document to a String or a Table

Tags: java, data-structures, lua, text-parsing

- I want to store the Data of the following structured Text/Lua document in a 
  Java Table, how can i  do this and
- Is there a Parser for Lua Structures?
- Or is there a Parser in Java which can read from { till }

```
   SavedVariablesFromProgrammXYZ =
   {   
       ["DefaultSettings"] = 
       {
           ["@Account1"] = 
           {
                   ["$AccountWideInfo"] = 
                   {
                       ["ListOfPersons"] = 
                       {
                           [8] = 
                           {
                               ...,
                               ["timeDone"] = 1570124931,
                               ["PersonName"] = "PersonName Y",
                               ...,
                           },
                           [1] = 
                           {
                               ...,
                               ["timeDone"] = 1570108908,
                               ["PersonName"] = "PersonName X",
                               ...,

                           },
                       },
                   },
                   ["OtherNotImportantVar"] = ...,
                   ["OtherNotImportantVar"] = ...,
                   ["OtherNotImportantVar"] = ...,
           },
           ["@Account2"] = 
           {
               -- // same structure
           },

       },
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach would probably be to leverage a Lua implementation which targets the JVM. Several are listed [here](http://lua-users.org/wiki/LuaImplementations). The one caveat there is that you'll need to consider sandboxing and limiting execution time if you don't trust the source of the Lua script.